# Selenium chromedriver crashes (ver 94)

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Tear out codes to bare minimum to troubleshoot

from selenium import webdriver

web = webdriver.Chrome()

web.get('https://www.google.com/')

Browser crashes i.e. opened and closed by itself

Google chrome is: Version 94.0.4606.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Tried with different version of chromedriver. There are 3 versions now:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=95.0.4638.10/
ver95: (got error message which confirms browser version)

Current browser version is 94.0.4606.54 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Ver 93 and 94: (browser crashes for both versions)

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=94.0.4606.41/
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=93.0.4577.63/

There is terminal message:
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51253/devtools/browser/832a4d53-90ec-4f5f-b106-5cc950719cb1
(Tried some suggestions but couldn’t resolve this too.)

Anyone has this problem recently and solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Browser crashes i.e. opened and closed by itself
```

Your this statement seems okay to me. Since you do not have any code written after

```
web.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

line, it is supposed to close the browser.

you can put some time.sleep(5) after the `.get()` call, and it would stand still.